# ComponentDidMount() not firing

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use the food2fork API to generate a list of dishes given a specific ingredient. ComponentDidMount() is not firing and thus nothing is being printed out. Currently My handleClick and handleChange methods do very little so I have omitted them. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly, as I fetch the data then change the state of recipes to the resulting count value. Below is the ComponentDidMount() code and my render method. If anyone could help that would be great, thank you!

```
class User extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: '',
      isLoaded: '',
      ingredientName: '',
      recipes: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  } 

  ComponentDidMount(){
    fetch("https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=0b23e639e2a708b56e4e8cb0f575dfbf&q=chicken&page=1")
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.json());
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result);
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          recipes: result.count
        });
      }
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p id="ingredientTitle">Enter Your Ingredients Below:</p>
        <input type="text" id="box" value={this.state.ingredientName} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <div className="formList">
            <form id="ingredientForm">
              <div className="Buttons">
                <button type="button" id="AddButton" >Add Ingredient</button>
                <button type="button" id="SubmitButton" onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            <h1>{this.recipes}</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Try componentDidMount?

Comment: Your component has most likely been unmounted before the request is complete. Make Api call in componentWillMount or constructor or check isMounted() to check if it's mounted

Comment: componentWillMount is deprecated. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
   ComponentDidMount()
```

To

```
  componentDidMount()
```

c should be in lowercase. Keep in mind that method names always starts with lowercase

Answer (score 0):

not ComponentDidMount() its componentDidMount()

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch("https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?key=0b23e639e2a708b56e4e8cb0f575dfbf&q=chicken&page=1");
    const json = await res.json();
    return json;
  }
```